# Why my github action's cron is not working?

Tags: cron, github-actions, cron-task

I have written a github actions workflow yml file to schedule a job to run everyday at a particular time but it's not working. I have even used the cron written in official doc but still it is not working. Is it due to Indian TimeZone or some other reason??

```
name: run app.py

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '30 4,17 * * *'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        
      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.9' # install the python version needed
          
      - name: install python packages
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          
      - name: execute py script # run main.py
        env:
          DSA_SHEET: ${{ secrets.DSA_SHEET }}
        run: python app.py
```

I have tried to change the cron many time but it was not working. It was only working when set to run every 5mins but when I set it to run everyday it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Github actions schedule is in UTC time.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule